# Disable auto pause on mobile YouTube site

Tags: youtube

I'll play some videos from YouTube and I'll add them to my playlist on Spotify. But everythime I'll change from the mobile YouTube website to the Spotify app, YouTube will pause the video. I hate this feature and would disable it. But how can I do that? I didn't find any setting to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, there isn't such a setting do disable this future on mobile. it has to do with "auto-focusing-on-active-app". you can try a few alternatives like:

- **[https://github.com/MinTube](https://github.com/imshyam/mintube)**
- **[https://github.com/NewPipe](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe)**

another approach would be **not** to use mobile YouTube site:

- open youtube.com in your mobile browser (Chrome / Firefox)
- go to the browser menu and choose **Desktop Site** to switch to the desktop version of the YouTube website
- tap the play button to start the YouTube video and then switch to any other app on your phone.
- YouTube will stop playback - no problem - just pull down the notification bar and tap the play icon in the drawer to resume playback.
- done... YouTube will now play in the background while you multi-task.